# How to chose the kernel in order to minimize the operator norm?

Tags: operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space and let $E\subset \mathcal{H}$ be a
closed subspace$.$

If we have a bounded invertible operator $A:E\rightarrow \mathcal{H}$, how
to chose a complementary subspace $F$ of $E$ in order to minimize :

$\underset{x\in E,y\in F}{\max }\frac{\left\Vert Ax\right\Vert }{\left\Vert
x+y\right\Vert }$

wich is the norm of an operator having $F$ as kernel and extending $A$.

Thank you !

Comment: Have you looked at $E^\perp$?

Comment: Yes and I think it is the right one.

Comment: To prove it, note that if $y \in E^\perp, y \ne 0$, then you are guaranteed that $\|x + y\| > \|x\|$.